# Why are element contents output when using <xsl:apply-templates />

Tags: xslt

when I open pstrong.xml (see below) in a browser, the following is output:

heading_1
this is the first paragraph

Please can you explain the following:

1) why the second line (this is the first paragraph) is output - since it is not done in the "pr" template?
    i.e. the "catalog" template is first invoked followed by the "pr" template. The "strong" template
    is then invoked which outputs the first line ("heading_1)

2) why do I not require "xsl:apply-templates" in the "strong" template?

// pstrong.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pstrong_current.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <pr><strong>heading_1</strong>this is the first paragraph</pr>
</catalog>
```

// pstrong_current.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
             <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pr">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) that kick in if you use `apply-templates` and don't have a matching template of your own.